# My program is not going inside the "if" part and it is always going in the "else" part

Tags: java, if-statement, jdbc, resultset

I have done the connection with Oracle 10g Xe database through the following code.

```
Context ctx=new InitialContext();
DataSource ds=(DataSource)ctx.lookup("java:OracleDS");
Connection con=ds.getConnection(); 

String mob=request.getParameter("mob_no");
String pass=request.getParameter("pass");
Statement stmt=con.createStatement();

//checking login details
String sql="select * from user1 where mob_no='"+mob+"' and password='"+pass+"'";
ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(sql);
String sql2="select * from postpaid where mob_no='"+mob+"'";
ResultSet rs2=stmt.executeQuery(sql2);

if(rs.isBeforeFirst())
{
    while(rs2.next())
    {  
        if(rs2.getInt(2)!=0)
        {
            out.println("You have total due of "+rs2.getInt(2));
            out.println("<a href=\"paybill.jsp\">Pay Bill</a>");
        }
        else {
            out.println("You have no dues!!!!!");
        }
    }
}
else
{
  out.println("Invalid login details.....<a href=\"#\">Back to home page</a>");
}
```

My program always shows the result "Invalid login Details"

Comment: i always get the output "Invalid login details".

Comment: you should fix formatting of brackets

Comment: make sure your first query is returning some result.

Comment: oh sorry for the formatting of brackets.. i just pasted the code  and didnt check what is i was postion

Comment: Sorry for the worng code earlier.I copy pasted wrong one.This new code is the one that i was having trouble with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation for `isBeforeFirst()` says:

> "Returns `true` if the cursor is before the first row; `false` if the cursor is at any other position **or the result set contains no rows**."

In this context, the `false` most likely means the latter; i.e. your result set is empty because no rows match the supplied user and password in the first query.

**UPDATE**

My answer is basically the same.  The final `else`  branch is taken because the first query matches no rows.

Why?

I could guess ... but instead, I suggest you print out the query SQL that you are executing to make sure that the statments are what they ought to be.

Another thing to note is that building queries like this:

```
  String sql="select * from user1 where mob_no='"+mob+"' and password='"+pass+"'";
```

is **dangerous**.  Suppose someone sent a request with a `mob_no` argument whose value was something like this:

```
  "foo' ; drop table user1 ;"
```

You should use a `PreparedStatement` with SQL like this:

```
  String sql = "select * from user1 where mob_no = ? and password = ?";
```

and use `PreparedStatement.setString(...)` to add the parameter values.

Comment: i have done some correction in the code....actually i am new to stackoverflow thats why by mistake i posted the wrong queston... i do not know the in and outs of this site